# Ansible ignoring "add_host"

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to fetch a file from a list of hosts in an inventory file, and then also from another host that has the same file on a different path.
I don't want to add this particular host on the inventory so I'm trying to manage it through the `add_host` module to the in-memory inventory

The problem is that plays are executed only on the hosts from the inventory file, and ignoring the one I'm adding with `add_host`.

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Play
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file_to_fecth: "/home/user/filename"
    dest_dir: "/tmp/"
  tasks:
    - name: add new host
      add_host:
        hostname: server.dns.name
        groups: addedgroup
        file_to_fecth: "/opt/dir/filename"


  hosts: all:addedgroup
  tasks:
    - name: Fetching file
      fetch:
        src: "{{ file_to_fecth }}"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ ansible_host }}_filename"
        flat: yes
```

Comment: Because your target is still `hosts: localhost`, start a new play with `hosts: addedgroup`, and you'll have those hosts targeted. (You **can** do that in the same YAML file).

Comment: Mind that the plays are a list (as the example on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution) and most likely, what you have there is just bogus and will yield an error somehow or have a really odd behaviour.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε but if you notice in the second play I'm targetting `hosts: all:addedgroup`, and in fatcs the fetchs are executed on the hosts presents on the inventory file, but not on the added host "server.dns.name"

Comment: You don't have a second play, as said, you have a bogus playbook, different plays should be different items of a **list**.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε  ok, I understand.
I'll post the correct version

Answer (score 1):

This is working, thanks to @β.εηοιτ.βε

```
---
- name: Play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: add new host
      add_host:
        hostname: server.dns.name
        groups: addedgroup
        file_to_fecth: "/opt/dir/filename"

- name: Play
  hosts: all:addedgroup
  vars:
    dest_dir: "/tmp/"
  tasks:
    - name: Fetching file
      fetch:
        src: "{{ file_to_fecth }}"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ ansible_host }}_filename"
        flat: yes
```